# I need send session between web1 to web2

Tags: c#, session

I have "web1(http:// localhost /web1)" and "web2(http:// localhost /web2)" but I need send session from web1 to web2.

I try to use "sessionstate" in "web.config" with "mode=SQLServer" and "mode=StateServer" that not complete. because I get error is "Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode".

So I need to any method for send session from "web1" to "web2" and then I necesary remain original value in session.

My environment. C#.net 4.0, SQL Server 2008, IIS 7.5

Comment: Why not use a database? You have SQL Server 2008.

Comment: web1 and web2 are different web applications, meaning different app domains, their session info would not be available anyways.  You are better off storing the values in a DB table that is not bound to a session.

Comment: are you familiar with QueryString in Web..? I am assuming  that you have the src for this project also show what you have done thus far on your own.. if they web sites reside in the same domain

Answer (score 1):

Sharing state not possible with default ASP.Net session state: all session state providers (in-memory, SQL and state server) partition sessions by sessionID + applicationID thus making it not possible to directly share session state.

If you need to share small amount of data cookies may be acceptable approach (may need to encrypt data there). Alternatively you can store data server side in your custom DB accessible to both applications and use custom ID to pass user/session ID.

Comment: Thank you Alexei Levenkov.
I will try follow to your method.